# My partitions are not visible

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, drive

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. Let me explain my situation.

I was using Windows 8 with a 500GB internal drive and one day my OS crashed and when I restarted it showed "missing Operating system". So I used Ubuntu USB booting and got into "Try Ubuntu".
The problem stats here. None of my drives are visible except for one in Files.

So I searched online, they said to type in various commands.
I am posting my those commands and outputs here. someone please give me a solution if you find the problem.

```
1."sudo fdisk-l"
```

shows
    Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors

same is repeated untill  /dev/ram15

then
    Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 102402047 101683200  48.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3  *    102402048 358899711 256497664 122.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       358899712 625139711 266240000   127G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Here I have to mention the total space don't add up to 500GB.

```
2.sudo gdisk   /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************
```

I pressed 'q'.

Is there a problem with partition table?
Or if there is any other problem please instruct me what to do.

[image: GParted's screen shot]

Comment: set your boot flag back to sda1

Comment: how to do that?? more info ps

Comment: use gparted on the live cd

Comment: in that? how to change the flag?

Comment: click the partition and manage flags

Comment: i pressed manage flags but it is loading forever by now

Comment: windows takes forever to load .... if you have a windows loading problem ask on super user. this site is for ubuntu

Comment: can you please tell me what to do after changing the flag

Comment: boot the computer

Answer (score 0):

The `gdisk` message about `Found invalid GPT and valid MBR...` most likely means that the disk *used to* contain a GUID Partition Table (GPT), but it was converted to use the older Master Boot Record (MBR) partitioning scheme by a tool that was either GPT-unaware or that did an incomplete job of wiping out the GPT data structures. If I had to guess, I'd say that the computer came pre-installed with Windows 8 or later -- most such computers boot in EFI mode and so would have used GPT. You then re-installed Windows in BIOS mode, which converted the disk from GPT to MBR form in an incomplete way. (The Windows tools will do this.)

Running the disk in this way is mostly OK, but can lead to confusion, and in an extreme case you might end up trashing the disk. You can remove the stray GPT data with `fixparts`, which comes with Ubuntu. See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) for details -- search on `GPT signatures detected` for the relevant section.

***Caveat:*** There's a *very slim* chance that something else has caused this discrepancy. For instance, if you'd been booting in EFI mode prior to your crash and something wrote out the partition table in MBR form, it could be that you'd see similar results. This doesn't seem very probable, though. If it *is* what happened, then using `fixparts` to wipe the stray GPT data would be making matters worse. For this reason, and because an attempt to restore the system to bootability might also be damaging, I strongly recommend you back up the disk, or at least your important user files, before doing anything else.

The stray GPT data isn't your main problem, though; you say you can't boot. As the computer seems to hold nothing but Windows, that's fundamentally a Windows problem, so you should ask about it on a Windows forum. (I see no evidence of an Ubuntu installation on the disk, although you've obviously used Linux tools to gather the disk information.) If you also have an Ubuntu installation, please clarify where it's installed, as that might be important. It's probably best to remove the stray GPT data *before* you attempt a repair, in case the GPT data would confuse the Windows repair tools or any other utility you might try to run.